# Is it possible to run Windows on Ubuntu Core?

Tags: virtualbox, windows, wine, snap, ubuntu-core

I want to run diverse Windows Softwares on a PC which runs Ubuntu Core. After that I want to access the API of the Software

My thoughts to make this happen are:

1. Install Windows with the necessary Softare inside VirtualBox. -> This is definitely possible
2. Pack VirtualBox as *.snap. -> **Is this possible? How?**
3. Install this Snap onto the Ubuntu Core machine.
4. Access the installed Windows Software API from another Snap.

Another possibility could be to install the the Software via Wine, but how to transfer it then to a snap and install it on the Ubuntu Core machine?

Comment: No. Last time I checked, wine was not for running Windows, and Vbox is not the same as Ubuntu Core.

Comment: I have Ubuntu installed to a USB device, VBox is installed from Ubuntu Software, Windows is installed on VBox, I am able to run AutoCAD, Solidworks, Photoshop and etc. It is a bit slow, but I am using a cheap flash drive. An external or internal SSD with lots of RAM could be much faster.

Comment: I am running [Ubuntu Core](https://ubuntu.com/core), not Ubuntu.
There is Gnome Boxes as Flatpak available. Since Flatpak is also a sandbox system like snap, can I run Gnome Boxes somehow on Ubuntu Core?

Comment: See `snap info clouds`: "summary:   Download and install Windows 10 in a VM"

Comment: I tried clouds and what I get is this error:`/snap/clouds/8/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`